# How to run java on every at 4:00 Pm

Tags: java

Hi i have simple program written in `java` ,i want to run this code on every at `4:00Pm`. I tried many solutions but nothing works for me

```
class Simple{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
     System.out.println("Hello Java");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Try to set CronJobs.
A `Cron-Job` is a Linux command used for scheduling tasks to be executed sometime in the future. This is normally used to schedule a job that is executed periodically – for example, to send out a notice every morning.

Comment: groovy_guy :Can you please update How to use it my case

Comment: You did not even tell us which OS you are using.

Comment: Identify the command line you use to run your program manually. Then if you're in windows, wrap the line into a script and use [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler). If you're under Linux, use [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). If you're under another OS, search the equivalent tool.

Comment: Matteo NNZ :i am successfully executing the script using ` Windows Task Scheduler` .In my script there is` thread.sleep` for 10 seconds. When my` batch file` starts executing the script it works fine until it reaches the spot where `sleep timer` is scheduled for 10 seconds. The batch file gets closed and` script fails` ,Now my whole concern is to hold this `batch file` for atleast `10-15 seconds.` I am using `mvn test` to run the `testNG.xml` file